# OptimizeMember / s2Member Notification API

Tags: wordpress, affiliate

I can't get the Payment Notification to fire in OptimizeMemeber (forked from s2Member).

How do I begin troubleshooting and what are some common causes of API Notifications not firing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out the Payment Notification in OptimizeMember doesn't fire until a payment is made **and a user completes registration.**

I was able to track this down by turning on debug output in the logging section of OptimizeMember, completing the transaction and reviewing the log (also available in the debug section).

Hope this helps someone out there that ran into the same issue.